# Rails NoMethodError for method I did not call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYRP1.png)

When trying to save a message object in my MessageController. Here is my controller.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.user = current_user
    @message.user_id = current_user.id

    if @message.user_email.nil?
        @message.user_email = current_user.email
    end

    if @message.save
        # UserMailer.send_email_to_admin(current_user.email).deliver
    else
        # redirect_to new_message_path(@message)
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:subject, :body, :user_email)
  end

end
```

And here is my model.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_email, presence: true
  validates :subject, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :message, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

I have no idea why this error is appearing because there are no methods named "message" in my app. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looking at your error, appears to be happening on `@message.save`. Can you try commenting out this whole block and testing to narrow down if this is where the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model you have a validation for the `message` field:

```
validates :message, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
```

Is that supposed to be a validation for your `body` field?:

```
validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
```

Before saving the record, the validator is calling the `message` method on the `Message` instance(`@message`) to check its presence and validate it. Since you don't have a column named `message` but have a validation for it, you will get the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: YES THATS IT! I just realize that and came back to find your answer. Good on you sir, thanks a ton :)